# HTML editor and image upload to server

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, when we work with any html editor, I often include images and text. How will images upload to a specific folder in the server and be saved as a relative path in the db. I Need this concept for a CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to store the image's relative path in the DB ? As there is no need, because the content html is saved in the DB and when you the retrieve that content that particular image will be shown in the content.

As far as I have used [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/), there is some setting required in the config file to set the path where the images are stored when user adds images in content.

Comment: would if please tell me CK Editor is free o paid product. can we use it in asp.net project.

Comment: Well, you can check from his webiste; But we are using this free version with code :)

Answer (score 2):

I was using CKEditor first but it was found a bit difficult to work with asp.net. So I moved to obout editor. I think your problem can be solved with obout html editor. check this link, [obout.com - Html Editor - Image upload](https://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/examples/Customize_ImageUploadAndInsert.aspx)